# Android 2.1 (API 7) String to bytesArray java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.getBytes

Tags: java, android, string, exception

In API 7 when try

```
val string = "string"
val bytes = string.toByteArray(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
```

I get this exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.getBytes

Is any way to get bytes from string without standard method? Looks like, conversion string to byte array starts with Api 8.

Answer (score 1):

There are versions of `getBytes()` on `String` that work back to API Level 1, such as [this one](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String?hl=en#getBytes(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Possible, it's a feature of device, which i use for tests(eBook), but all methods of getBytes() ends with this exception.